# Get 10 percent of total time difference in java

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have:

```
Date d1 = 16:00:00
Date d2 = 19:00:00

long result =  d2.getTime() - d1.getTime(); // will result in 3 hours. 
Date d = new Date(result);
print(d.getMinutes);
```

How can I get the 10 percent of the 3 hours in minutes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with getting it the traditional way?

```
long result = d2.getTime() - d1.getTIme();
double tenthOfResult = result * .1;
Date d = new Date((long)tenthOfResult);
System.out.println(d.getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood task correctly, something like:

```
long result =  d2.getTime() - d1.getTime(); // will result in 3 hours. 
result = (result - d1.getTime()) / 10 + d1.getTime(); //Notice this line
Date d = new Date(result);
print(d.getMinutes());
```

This will result in d1.getTime + 10% of 3 hours